# Class diagram mapping to ERD

Tags: sql, select, uml, class-design, erd

I have the following class diagram with no more informations related to multiplicity or any other thing.
I have to propose a relational database based only on this diagram so I would need to ask the community opinion whether I did well or not.
Please share your view.
Thank you.

[image]

I need to propose a database relation, I added:[image]

Needs to select all "Services-Serviciu" which expose "Capabilites-Capabilitate" from de list of "Dependencies-Dependenta" of RayTracingEngine "Services"

I made the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
Serviciu s
INNER JOIN Capabilitate C ON s.id = c.id_C
INNER JOIN Dependenta d ON s.id = d.id_D
WHERE d.id_D = c.id_C AND s.nume = "RayTracingEngine"
```

Can you please help me if I did well or needs something to be changed ?
Thank you.

Comment: You are using a shared composition wjhich per UML 2.5 definition does not have a common semantics and needs explanation. So: what does it mean?

Comment: There is no way of knowing if this is correct if you don't specify multiplicities on your associations in the UML diagram.

Comment: @GeertBellekens shouldn't it be specified also in class-diagram ?

Comment: @qwerty_so I only got a class-diagram no more details.. based on that I made and ERD diagram and I asked the community opinion whether is correct or not. Why question had to be closed ? There's no more details.

Comment: @GeertBellekens shouldn't you assume multiplicity is 1 by default if was not specified ?

Comment: Sure there is a default if not specified, but I'm not sure if it's [1..1]. In any case, having the same multiplicity ([1..1] or any other) everywhere would make no sense at all, so I assumed the multiplicities are simply missing.

Comment: Only the class diagram is a UML diagram. the hand drawn diagram is not UML.

Comment: @GeertBellekens did I say it's UML ? I just asked whether the ERD (the hand drawn one) is correct or not based on class diagram.. If not correct what needs to be changed.
I'm interested whether relation between Dependenta and Capabilitate is made right or not(Dependenta contain id_Cap as Foreign key from Capabilitate for the relation)

Comment: You asked "shouldn't it be specified also in class-diagram" I said you needed multiplicities on the *UML* diagram to be able to know if your ERD is correct. Since the class diagram is the only UML diagram, I did mean the class diagram is missing multiplicities.

Comment: @GeertBellekens thanks, that's how the asssigment looks, I cannot ask for multiplicity for class diagram.

Comment: then I guess you'll have to infer the multiplicities based on your functional knowledge of the domain. Since the names of the classes are not in English we can't help you with that here.

Comment: Serviciu-Service(nume-name, CPU-CPU, RAM-RAM, lansare -launch terminare - stop)
ServiciuVM- VmService(system_operare- OS, script-script, suspendare-suspend)
Capabilitate - Capability (nume-name, atribut- attribute)
Dependenta- Dependency(nume-name)